# Does arcpy have any tools for transforming field values in a fieldmapping?

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-10.1

I built my fieldmappings and, for the most part, everything is working. I recall reading somewhere that I could also use fieldmappings to transform field values during the import process. Unfortunately, I can't find the link where I read this. For example, in field ABC, replace value "1" with "TRUE" or if field ABC is null, replace it with DOG.

Can I do achieve this using tools within arcpy? Or, do I need to build this from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

Not with fieldmapping.

With the FieldMap object, you can do a few simple things like control how values from multiple fields are merged into a single value, or cut off text fields by position. But if you want to handle logical decisions like you're describing, I tend towards pairing together SearchCursor (on the input) and InsertCursor (on a new output you create).